# ¿Cómo puedo sumar los valores de los usuarios repetidos en este diccionario de Python?

Tags: python, diccionarios

El diccionario es:

```
user_horas =[{'user': 'Carlos Morales', 'stunden': 0.5}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 4.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 2.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 3.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 3.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 6.0}, {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 0.5}, {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 4.0}, {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 4.0}, {'user': 'Meiko Mehnert', 'stunden': 1.0}]
```

Quiero obtener la suma de los valores de los usuarios repetidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
user_horas =[{'user': 'Carlos Morales', 'stunden': 0.5}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 4.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 2.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 3.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 3.0}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 6.0}, {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 0.5}, {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 4.0}, {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 4.0}, {'user': 'Meiko Mehnert', 'stunden': 1.0}]
print(user_horas)

usuarios = []

for i in range(len(user_horas)):
    if user_horas[i]['user'] not in usuarios:
        usuarios.append(user_horas[i]['user'])

while len(user_horas) > len(usuarios):
    for i in range(len(user_horas)):
        try:
            if user_horas[i]['user'] == user_horas[i+1]['user']:
                user_horas[i]['stunden'] += user_horas[i+1]['stunden']
                user_horas.pop(i+1)
        except:
            pass

print("\nResultado:")
print(user_horas)
```

La lista `usuarios` se inicializa como vacía y con el bucle `for i in range(len(user_horas)):` se añaden los nombres de usuario, salvo que ya estén (evita duplicados).

Mientras haya más elementos en el diccionario que en la lista, se recorre el diccionario en búsqueda de nombres repetidos. Si se da ese caso, se añaden los puntos al elemento que aparece primero, y se elimina el segundo.

El resultado es:

```
[{'user': 'Carlos Morales', 'stunden': 0.5}, {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 36.0}, {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 6.5}, {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 8.0}, {'user': 'Meiko Mehnert', 'stunden': 1.0}]
```

Comment: Gracias Angel me ha sido de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Yo crearía un diccionario a parte en el que fueras guardando las claves y los valores de los usuarios, por ejemplo, llamado `users_suma`. Entonces, con un bucle recorres todo el diccionario inicial llamado `user_horas` y vas haciendo la siguiente comprobación:

- Si el nombre de usuario que estoy recorriendo ahora no está en el diccionario `users_suma`, me lo añades como clave y el valor que tiene del diccionario `user_horas`.
- En caso de que SÍ esté la clave añadida al diccionario `users_suma`, que te coja el valor que tiene y le sume el valor nuevo que está leyendo del diccionario `user_horas`.

Te lo pongo mejor con código. yo lo haría así.

```
user_horas =[{'user': 'Carlos Morales', 'stunden': 0.5},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 4.0},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 2.0},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 3.0},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 3.0},
             {'user': 'Ignazio Marino', 'stunden': 8.0},
             {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 6.0},
             {'user': 'Lukas Roscher', 'stunden': 0.5},
             {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 4.0},
             {'user': 'Maximilian Erhart', 'stunden': 4.0},
             {'user': 'Meiko Mehnert', 'stunden': 1.0}]

users_suma = {} #Diccionario vacío donde guardaremos las sumas

for i in user_horas:
    if users_suma.get(i['user']) != None:
        #Si el valor existe, es decir, que nos devuelve diferente a None, le sumamos a la clave el valor
        users_suma[i['user']] += i['stunden']
    else:
        #Si el valor no existe, es decir, que nos devuelve a None, le asignamos una nueva clave con un valor
        users_suma[i['user']] = i['stunden']

print(users_suma)
```

Te devolverá al imprimir un resultado como este.

```
{'Carlos Morales': 0.5, 
'Ignazio Marino': 36.0, 
'Lukas Roscher': 6.5, 
'Maximilian Erhart': 8.0, 
'Meiko Mehnert': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución:

```
lista = sorted([(dato['user'], dato['stunden']) for dato in user_horas], key=lambda dato: dato[0])
for k, g in groupby(lista,key=lambda dato: dato[0] ):
    suma = sum([x[1] for x in g])
    print(k, suma)
```

produce:

```
Carlos Morales 0.5
Ignazio Marino 36.0
Lukas Roscher 6.5
Maximilian Erhart 8.0
Meiko Mehnert 1.0
```

**Explicación**

La expresión

```
[(dato['user'], dato['stunden']) for dato in user_horas]
```

trasforma la lista de diccionarios en una lista de tuplas:

```
[('Carlos Morales', 0.5), ('Ignazio Marino', 8.0), ('Ignazio Marino', 4.0), ('Ignazio Marino', 2.0), ('Ignazio Marino', 8.0), ('Ignazio Marino', 3.0), ('Ignazio Marino', 3.0), ('Ignazio Marino', 8.0), ('Lukas Roscher', 6.0), ('Lukas Roscher', 0.5), ('Maximilian Erhart', 4.0), ('Maximilian Erhart', 4.0), ('Meiko Mehnert', 1.0)]
```

Para ordenar la lista por nombre, uso `sort`:

```
sorted([(dato['user'], dato['stunden']) for dato in user_horas], key=lambda dato: dato[0])
```

Con el parámetro `key` digo como ordenar: por cada tupla, use el dato en la primera posición (nombre) para hacer la comparación.

Lo anterior produce una lista ordenada de tuplas. Usando `groupby` puede recuperar la lista en "paquetes" que contiene el nombre de un usuario y un iterador para recorrer sus notas. Los datos se ven asi (escribiendo un pequeño ejemplo):

```
for k, g in groupby(lista,key=lambda dato: dato[0]):
    print(k)
    for nota in g:
        print(nota)

Carlos Morales
('Carlos Morales', 0.5)
Ignazio Marino
('Ignazio Marino', 8.0)
('Ignazio Marino', 4.0)
('Ignazio Marino', 2.0)
('Ignazio Marino', 8.0)
('Ignazio Marino', 3.0)
('Ignazio Marino', 3.0)
('Ignazio Marino', 8.0)
Lukas Roscher
('Lukas Roscher', 6.0)
('Lukas Roscher', 0.5)
Maximilian Erhart
('Maximilian Erhart', 4.0)
('Maximilian Erhart', 4.0)
Meiko Mehnert
('Meiko Mehnert', 1.0)
```

Teniendo el nombre del usuario y el iterador para recuperar sus notas, sólo resta hacer un `sum` con el iterador.

Eso seria todo.